# Firefox fork that allows to use old addons but still keeps new vulnerabilities patched in time?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I kind of like my Firefox as it is. I'd use it for years to come, but I'm afraid it will be exploitable as hell in just a few years if I'll just stop updating it.

There are many addons that probably will never be rewritten, and the new addon API will probably be too limited to compete with the current one.

I wonder if somebody made a version of Firefox that is compatible with old addons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox version 57, the developers have decided to drop the XUL
add-on format, now called "Legacy", in favor of WebExtensions,
which in plain English are very similar to Google Chrome extensions.

Two Firefox forks that keep the legacy add-ons are :

- [Waterfox](https://www.waterfoxproject.org/) (the one recommended by Mozilla)
- [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/)

I have tried Waterfox, and it very nicely imported all my add-ons and profile
data. Screen layout was lost and so some small customizations were still
required, but in general this is basically almost a duplicate of Firefox.

Edit: I now use Pale Moon which is much faster than Waterfox.
It is maybe even competitive with Firefox Quantum as regarding speed.